# My smartphone battery was damaged

Tags: battery, motorola-moto-g

Can I change battery for my Motor G (Motorola)? My smartphone's battery was damaged. What can I do with it? It say that I shouldn't remove the battery

Comment: You could look up how to do it yourself, or if you are not comfortable doing it (and voiding your warranty) take it to a repair centre, or the vendor you purchased it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @RossC's comment, doing this yourself is quite easy if you are confident and comfortable with device disassembly, and have the correct tools. There are tutorials on how to safely and correctly replace this:

1. iFixIt: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+X+Battery+Replacement/16974
2. ETradeSupply video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd3AZSXhOf8

From experience, I strongly suggest you watch the entire video and/or read the whole article before ever even starting. That way no surprises creep up on you, and you already have an idea as to everything you'll need to do.

Tools can be found widely online and may be worth the investment ([$2 kit on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004D1OERM), [$1.35 kit on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/9-in-1-Screwdriver-Repair-Kit-Set-Open-Cell-Phone-PentalobeTorx-Pry-Tools-PC-/310766043489?pt=US_Cell_Phone_PDA_Cases&hash=item485b198161)).

Note that this might void any warranty you have from Motorola or your device's distributor. You could check with them first and see if the repairs might be covered for free or a fee. Motorola can always [help](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/mcp/service/) but may cost you more money (if you are at fault for the damage) or can take a while to complete due to shipping, service backlog, etc.